# Symfony2: LiipImagineBundle - Exception: Unable to generate a URL for the named route "_imagine_image_upload_thumbnail" as such route does not exist

Tags: php, symfony, twig, liipimaginebundle

I am using [LiipImagineBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle)

I have followed installing instruction as in the documentation

in AppKernel.php

```
new Liip\ImagineBundle\LiipImagineBundle(),
```

and in routing.yml

```
# app/config/routing.yml

_imagine:
    resource: .
    type:     imagine
```

And in config.yml

```
#app/config/config.yml
liip_imagine:
    filter_sets:
        image_upload_thumbnail:
            quality: 85
            filters:
                thumbnail: { size: [150, 150], mode: outbound }
```

and in my twig file

```
<img alt="{{ media.title|default('untitled') }}" src="{{ media.getWebPath | imagine_filter('image_upload_thumbnail') }}"/>
```

I get this error

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "_imagine_image_upload_thumbnail" as such route does not exist.")
```

**What i have tried :**

- Cache clear
- php app/console router:debug |  grep imagine  found none
- Route dosen't exist and not registered
- Validated that i have `media/cache` folder with the right permissions

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

remove the spaces:

```
{{ media.webPath|imagine_filter('...') }}
```

... or invoke as a function:

```
{{ imagine_filter( media.webPath, 'filtername', false ) }}
```

---

Twig seems to invoke `imagine_filter` as a twig function instead of as a twig filter.

You end up with `media.webPath` not being passed as an argument.

( tip: just use `media.webPath` instead of `media.getWebPath` - twig will automatically call the getter for you )

Actually the [underlying function `filter()`](https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle/blob/master/Templating/ImagineExtension.php#L43) accepts the image-path as the first and the filter-name as it's second argument.

The third argument (boolean) determines wether to generate a relative or absolute url - defaults to false (relative).

Curently imagine uses the filter-name as a route-name and tries to generate a url ... which of course doesn't work :)

Comment: Thanks @nifr for your answer, but it didn't work, problem is route did not exist, not even when I run `php app/console router:debug | grep imagine`

Comment: You need to follow the instructions and add this to your routing.yml: `_imagine:
    resource: .
    type:     imagine`

Comment: I have the same problem as @AhmedSamy.

Comment: @MateoTibaquirá the instructions you told us to add are already done but with no result!

Comment: It's mentioned in the question that the `_imagine` route-resource was included correctly in `routing.yml` @MateoTibaquirá. This doesn't seem to be the problem here.

Comment: @aminejallouli what versions of symfony (and the bundle) are you using?

Comment: @nifr I am using symfony 2.3 and `"liip/imagine-bundle": "1.0.*@dev"`

Comment: problem is fixed if I upgraded to Symfony 2.3